# How to test dynamic changes to the DOM via JavaScript with Jest or some other testing library?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, jsdom

I am dynamically adding a `<script>` tag to the document `<head>` on page load based on the environment.

The Function:

```js
export const loadScript = () => {
  // load script tag into head
  const HEAD = document.getElementsByTagName('head')
  const SCRIPT_TAG = document.createElement('script')
  SCRIPT_TAG.setAttribute('src', process.env.SCRIPT_SRC)
  SCRIPT_TAG.setAttribute('async', true)
  HEAD[0].append(SCRIPT_TAG)
}
```

I want to write a test that checks if once the `loadScript()` function is run that the `<script>` tag made it into the head. Our environment is set up with Jest, and I haven't found a satisfactory example that demonstrates how to do it, or works.

I am new to testing, and would appreciate any solutions, or hints offered.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the easiest way to test it would be something like this:

```js
test('loadScript', () => {
  process.env.SCRIPT_SRC = 'the-src';
  loadScript();
  expect(document.head.innerHTML).toBe('<script src="the-src" async="true"></script>');
});
```

This works because the default [test environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testenvironment-string) for `Jest` is `jsdom` which simulates the `document`.

Answer (score 0):

```
test('loadScript', () => {
  loadScript();
  const script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  // trigger the callback
  script.onreadystatechange(); // or script.onLoad();
  expect("something which you have on load").toBe('expected result on load');
});
```

Comment: Adding some details will be helpful as to why this will work.